# Get multiple subcounts in MongoDB aggregate pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

The model of the docs is as follows :

```
{
    _id: ObjectID,
    name: String,
    taxonomy: {
       segment : Number,
       class : Number,
       subclass : Number,
    }
}
```

I'm running an aggregate query that groups the docs by "taxonomy.segment", counts each document within each, and gives me the unique "class" and "subclass" values for each group, with a lookup on the segment details for extra info.

```
db.getCollection('global_products').aggregate([{
        $group :{
            _id : {
                seg:'$taxonomy.segment'
            },
            count : {
                $sum : 1
            },
            classes: { 
                $addToSet:{ 
                    code:'$taxonomy.class'
                },
            },
            subclasses: { 
                $addToSet:{
                    code:'$taxonomy.subclass'
                }
            },
        }
    },{
        $lookup: {
            from:'global_taxonomy',localField:'_id.seg',foreignField:'code', as:'segment_details'
        }
    },
])
```

I'd like to add the counts for each type of classes and subclasses, but can't seem to figure out a way. is it possible using the aggregate pipeline?

To clarify, I would like to add `subcount` values in the following JSON :

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "seg" : 64000000
    },
    "count" : 1906,
    "classes" : [ 
        {"code" : 64010200, subcount:x}, 
        {"code" : 64010300, subcount:y}, 
        {"code" : 64010100, subcount:z}
    ],
    "subclasses" : [ 
        {"code" : 64010200, subcount:s}, 
        {"code" : 64010300, subcount:t}, 
        {"code" : 64010100, subcount:u}
    ],
    "segment_details" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("572c8eba2b311f69f9c1666a"),
            "code" : 64000000,
            "name" : "Main Stock",
            "type" : "segment"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like below. You'll have to do one grouping at a time while counting the no of rows in that group. You'll need three groups one for each subclass, class and segment respectively. I'll see if Mongo 3.4 have some shorter way of approaching this.

```
aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            seg: '$taxonomy.segment',
            classcode: '$taxonomy.class',
            subclasscode: '$taxonomy.subclass'
        },
        subclasscount: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            seg: '$_id.seg',
            classcode: '$_id.classcode'
        },
        subclasses: {
            $addToSet: {
                code: '$_id.subclasscode',
                subcount: '$subclasscount'
            }
        },
        classcount: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            seg: '$_id.seg'
        },
        classes: {
            $addToSet: {
                code: '$_id.classcode',
                subcount: '$classcount'
            }
        },
        subclasses: {
            $first: '$subclasses'
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'global_taxonomy',
        localField: '_id.seg',
        foreignField: 'code',
        as: 'segment_details'
    }
}])
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything, output says : http://pastebin.com/1pe2kc3C

Comment: Can you add your input collection for me to test ?

Comment: preparing the data showed me my typo, it is in fact working perfectly, thanks!